# Sublime Text 3 "Services" Missing from right-click

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way to add Services to the right-click dialog?

Im pretty sure it used to be there, but right now I have to click SublimeText to access it form the Main menu bar.

ST3 OSX 10.10.3

Comment: No, this was never in the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

This link [ST Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8680) is old, but I'm guessing it is still not a feature.

I wanted it for Dash look-up, and I ended up making a global keyboard shortcut.
[Instructions found Here](https://kapeli.com/dash_guide#lookUpInDashSystemService)